# biblatex APA citation not working

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

This is what I used

```
\usepackage[style=apa, backend = biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

in text I am doing

```
\cite{last2011}
```

the output is giving
(abbreviation of First). Last, 2011
when it should be
Last, 2011

Am I doing something wrong? or am I just misunderstanding how APA works? my PI basically just went on a highlighting spree of my manuscript for wrong APA style.

Also, this issue occurs in only some of the citations. Checked to see if there was any difference between the bibtex and there's nothing wrong. really confused

Edit:
thanks for all the comments. I figured out what's wrong or what's not wrong in this case. Nothing is wrong with biblatex or my script. It is just that some citations have authors with the same last name so it clarifies using first initial as per APA 7th edition rules.

very careless on my part. I will let my PI know lol. Sorry for the vague post, I'm new to all this. will keep all your suggestions in mind moving forward!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which version of the `biblatex-apa` style and which version of `biber` you employ.

Comment: It's really hard to see what you're doing with a code fragment. Can you at least show us a complete `.bib` file entry and a better description of what the wrong output is. Is the citation callout incorrect or the formatting of the bibliography itself or both? And are *all* of your citations not working, or just some of them?

Comment: It's not so easy to say what is going on in your document, but let me please note that it can be correct APA style to have a given name initial in citations: https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but unless your LaTeX installation is more than four years old you won't need `\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}`.#

Comment: As the link https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/citations/basic-principles/citing-authors-same-surname discusses APA style wants given name initials in some cases, but not in all. So the behaviour you describe may very well be entirely correct according to APA style rules. We, however, cannot tell you anything more useful if you cannot share a small example document that reproduces the output you are asking about with as little code as possible. You need to share relevant `.bib` entries as well.

Comment: thanks for all the comments. I figured out what's wrong or what's not wrong in this case. Nothing is wrong with biblatex or my script. It is just that some citations have authors with the same last name so it clarifies using first initial as per APA 7th edition rules.

very careless on my part. I will let my PI know lol. Sorry for the vague post, I'm new to all this. will keep all your suggestions in mind moving forward!